# Java HTTP server will not create context for a file

Tags: java, http

```
    public static void registerFiles(String dir) {
        String[] pathnames;
        File f = new File(dir);
        pathnames = f.list();
        for (String pathname : pathnames) {
            currentFile = dir;  
            server.createContext("/data/"+ pathname, new Handlers.FileHandler());
            System.out.println("/data/"+ pathname);
        }
    }
```

In the "Handlers" class:

```
    public static class FileHandler implements HttpHandler {

        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange he) throws IOException {
            File file = new File(SimpleHttpServer.currentFile);
            he.sendResponseHeaders(200, file.length());
            OutputStream outputStream=he.getResponseBody();
            Files.copy(file.toPath(), outputStream);
            outputStream.close();
        }
    }
```

When I get rid of the "createContext", and just print the line, it says:

`/data/tes.mp3`
Which is correct.
But, when I use the "createContext"

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ******.******.******.SimpleHttpServer.registerFiles(SimpleHttpServer.java:51) (this is the create context line)
    at ******.******.******.Main.main(Main.java:20)
```

I think the code looks fine, does anybody see a problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Is `server` null?

Comment: It was, but I fixed that by running the code for the main create contexts first. But now, the mp3 file shows no response, and the page is blank.